# Using TAB to exit a TMemo component

Tags: delphi, tmemo

I have a requirement to allow users to tab around a Delphi application screen in a certain order.  This is fine for almost everything, except that I can't seem to find a way to tab OUT of a memo component.   I realise that Tab, itself, is a legitimate key in a memo for formatting purposes.

Does anyone know if it is possible at all to tab to the next control from a Tmemo?   I don't need the Tab format in the Memo, so I'm quite happy to sacrifice that.

I'm using Delphi 5 Enterprise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you set the TMemo's WantTabs property to False, pressing Tab in the memo should move to the next control.

Comment: Yes, I set WantTabs to False.  Sorry, should have mentioned that.   It makes no difference.  Press the Tab key and the focus remains on the Memo control.   I decided I must be misinterpreting it and set it to True, just to be sure.  Nope!

Comment: I would suggest. Create a simple new Project. Only `TMemo` and a `TEdit` component. If you can not leave the `TMemo` then something is wrong with D5 or OS.(`Memo1.WantTabs := False;`)

Comment: Now you're worrying me, but thanks, I will try that.

Comment: worse case, you might need to subclass the Memo to handle the `WM_GETDLGCODE` message, first passing it to the default handler and then removing the `DLGC_WANTTAB` flag from the result. Or, in the Memo's `OnKeyPress` event, you can send a `WM_NEXTDLGCTRL` or `CM_DIALOGKEY(VK_TAB)` message to the Form when the `Key` parameter is `#9`.

Comment: I found myself almost always being able to SHIFT+TAB out of multiline controls. Yes, it's the other direction, but it's a way.

Comment: Thanks for all the guidance, people.  Very much appreciated.   I'll "have a play" with your suggestions when I get a chance later in the week and let you know.  Regards!

Comment: Thank you to moskito-x for pointing out the obvious approach.   I did as you suggested and there was no problem with tabbing out of the memo.   Had a poke around in my project and realised that I had created a VK_TAB action in the OnKeyUp event for the memo component which overrode the component default action.   Ace!

Comment: Can someone tell me how to accept moskito-x's comment as an answer so I can credit him/her with it, please?

Comment: @Capfka : Glad you found the reason. I think upvote my comment is enough.